# Windows 11/MinGW 64-Bit: QT-Application not starting from "C:/Program Files" but from anywhere else

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw

I've ported a Qt 5.12.12 application from Linux to Windows 11 using the Toolchain coming together with the Qt-Installer: QtCreator, MinGW 7.30, amd64, C++. So far, everything works out fine except when I deploy the app (via a Inno Setup Studio Installer, all the used *.dll files included) to "Program Files".

When the program (named "orange") resides in `C:/Program Files/ORANGE/orange.exe` it will never start, except when "run as administrator". When I rename the exact folder `C:/Program Files/ORANGE` to `C:/ORANGE`, then everything works fine without "admin privileges"; the app runs flawlessly. Same on any folder on `D:/` drive.

When starting from `C:/Program Files/ORANGE/orange.exe` the program fails silently, but in the Windows event log I can see an entry like that in "Computer Management->System Tools->Event Viewer->Custom Views->Administrative Events":

```
Faulting application name: orange.exe, version: 1.1.0.0, time stamp: 0x61ca2b05
Faulting module name: libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x000000000000d125
Faulting process id: 0x5b90
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7fb68b04bbb8e
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\ORANGE\orange.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\ORANGE\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
Report Id: 3ccd12e6-cfd5-4cff-8d1b-c5450716a821
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I'm not usually a Windows-Developer so any help on howto further debug or resolve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds strange, I'm not sure what's happening. I guess I'd start to check which users/groups have the execution privilege on that file (granting it to `Everyone`), then I'd try to disable the windows defender real time protection.

Comment: What happens with spaces in the path? What about `c:\ora nge`?

Comment: C:\Program Files is protected by UAC. Does your program attempt to write any files in the same location as your executable?

Comment: @drescherjm: You got it right - the program tried to write logfiles to its working directory. Windows should be a little more loquacious about the reasons for failure...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that @drescherjm got it right: My app did try to write logfiles to its own working directory (which was fine on my prior Linux setup). Moving the log-location to `%appdata%` (i.e. `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)`) did resolve the issue.

...as I'm using boost::log I was mislead by the reference to `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` in the error log. Reminds me of improving/reviewing log clarity ;)

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi the best way to find out if this is a permission error or a dependency problem (or both :) is to download the dependency walker https://www.dependencywalker.com/ and run it on the .exe file.
In your case it seems that it is looking for a library (.dll) in your local folder instead of the runtime folder (which probably can only be accessed by administrator)

The solution would be either

Change the libraries folder permissions as suggested in above
comments

Change the privileges of your normal user to a power user
(local admin with explicit access to admin folders)

Add the path of
the referenced library to the PATH in Systems Environment Variables